# MongoDB return all fields for mutliple documents

Tags: mongodb, select

I want to return from MongoDB all fields from multiple documents.

Example:

[image]

So, how to get this result?

Comment: by fields you mean all keys, all values or all the pairs key:values????

Comment: Check the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a `find()` and you will get a list of documents with the dictionary of first and second...